# "Your (something)" vs. "Your own (something)"

Tags: word-meaning, difference, word-usage

I frequently hear this expression :

> possessive pronoun + own + something

To what extent is that composition different from that one :

> possessive pronoun + something

For example :

"Your own company" & "Your company".

I know they are identical, but what's the real significance of the addition of the word "own" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, "*own*" emphasizes sole personal ownership:

> Used with a possessive to emphasize that someone or something belongs or relates to the person mentioned

It often distinguishes *individual* ownership from *shared* or *less-than-complete* ownership:

> I used to share a truck with my brother, but tomorrow I'm buying my own car.
>
> I worked at Megacorp, Inc. for twenty years, but now I'm starting my own company.
>
> We moved out of our apartment into our own house.

In those cases, I have a car or a company, but it's not *my own* car or company (though I may be allowed to drive it or I may work there). The last case, I've moved out of a shared apartment building into a privately-owned house.

Consider the sentence:

> Bob, stop eating my cookies! Buy your own food!

Using only "buy your food" here sounds a bit strange. Using "your own food" is much more natural. To express the same sentiment without using "own", you could say:

> Bob, stop eating my cookies! Buy some food for yourself!

Sometimes, *own* is used purely for emphasis, showing that the object is greatly desired or loved:

> Just think of it: if I can get this new client, I'll have my very own corner office!
>
> When I'm a millionaire, I'll buy a giant pool and my very own team of sled dogs!

In this case of a greatly loved object, it's also appropriate to use "*very own*", e.g., "*my **very** own team of sled dogs*". This is generally used to intensify the statement and express excitement. To use an example above:

> I worked at Megacorp, Inc. for twenty years, but now I'm starting my very own company!

In this case, I am obviously very excited about starting my new company.

Comment: Thanks! could you explain "very own" a little more ? please.